# Dual Booting Linux with Windows using Plop

Tags: dual-boot

I want to dual bot any Linux with my Windows xp in an old pc.
My problem was that my BIOS Don't support USB Booting.
And can't burn a dvd (DVD-RW not available).
the only way i found was to Boot with USB but as said earlier.

I was searching for alternative ways to install a new os. Then i found Plop Manager.

I want to ask that Can i dual bot through USB [ Linux (Ubuntu or anyother) with windows ] using Plop Manager...

or Plop manager is only used to install a new OS and Don't provide Dual booting.

Please Tell, And if any good tutorial (video tutorial) available, Please share the link or send me in pm ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Plop Boot Manager allows you to boot from USB, although depending on what system you have, it might not work because of hardware or software issues.

By itself, Plop is technically a bootloader. In order to get it to do anything, you have to supply it with a disk that contains a operating system (if it's a installer, it will load the installer to install that OS into your computer. If it's a live system, it will load the OS from the flash drive onto RAM)

If you want to set up dual-boot, just boot Plop into your CD drive at startup, and plug in your flash drive in a USB port, then select "USB" in Plop Boot Manager. It will load the mass storage drivers required to read your flash drive, then boot from it.

Although if you use a Ubuntu-based distro, upon installation it will usually find a Windows partition and ask if you want to "install Ubuntu alongside it" if it finds one.